# How to style Wordpress widget in sidebar with Bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, widget

I'm using Bootstrap to create a Wordpress site. I have registered the sidebar and am adding plugins (widgets) to the sidebar. I don't know how to style them properly.

This is what I have:
I can't post images, because I don't have 10 rep points. Screenshot is the list as is it now shows: a bullet point list with standard layout.

This is the HTML:

```
<aside id="recent_faqtax-2" class="widget recent-faqtax-widget"><h3 class="widget-title">FAQ</h3><ul>   <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="http://www.mysite/topics/packing/" title="View all posts filed under Packing">Packing</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://www.mysite/topics/pricing/" title="View all posts filed under Pricing">Pricing</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="http://www.mysite/topics/volume-2/" title="View all posts filed under Volume">Volume</a>
</li>
</ul></aside>
```

However, with Bootstrap I want to create this:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Packing
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Pricing</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Volume</a>
</div>
```

So it looks like this (in Chrome developer tools)

again, no image, but its the standard active list group in bootstrap.

How do I do this? Do I need to add a class in jQuery to the widget class? Can I do it with custom CSS?

Comment: You may want to upload the screenshots manually to imgur.com and just link to them. Then somebody with the privileges will surely edit your post to embed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually modify the code that generate the plugin. But the easiest way to do what you want is to add a text box in your sidebar and manually write there your code. So you will have something like:

```
 <div class="list-group">
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Packing
     </a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Pricing</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Volume</a>
    </div>
```

in the widget box and as output:

```
<aside id="recent_faqtax-2" class="widget recent-faqtax-widget">
<div class="list-group">
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Packing
     </a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Pricing</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Volume</a>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: thanks so much! simple solution, but very effective.

Comment: one problem though, it seems: the active class doesnt switch to the item that is active at that moment... it stays at the initial item. is that also fixable?